# Querying geonames for rows 1000-1200

Tags: web-services, geonames

I have been querying Geonames for parks per state.  Mostly there are under 1000 parks per state, but I just queried Conneticut, and there are just under 1200 parks there.

I already got the 1-1000 with this query:

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=CT&maxRows=1000

But increasing the maxRows to 1200 gives an error that I am querying for too many at once.  Is there a way to query for rows 1000-1200 ?

I don't really see how to do it with their API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [`startRow`](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) parameter in the query to page results. The documentation notes that it takes an integer value (`0` based indexing) and should be

> Used for paging results. If you want to get results 30 to 40, use startRow=30 and maxRows=10. Default is 0.

So to get the next 1000 data points (1000-1999), you should change your query to

```
http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=demo&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=CT&maxRows=1000&startRow=1000
```

I'd suggest reducing the `maxRows` to something manageable as well - something that will put less of a load on their servers *and* make for quicker responses to your queries.